# Need help in regex to match the string

Tags: regex, regex-group

below is a dataset

**com.jav.orgs.exceptions.sessionException: A1234- problem accessing the session at com.jav.orgview.OpenSessionJVM(JVM Method)**

im trying to extract  com.jav.orgs.exceptions.sessionException: A1234- problem accessing the session

REGEX = exceptions.sessionException:(?[\s\w-]+ )

OUTCOME =  A1234- problem accessing the session at

EXPECTED REsULT = A1234- problem accessing the session

need help in removing at the end

Comment: Maybe `exceptions\.sessionException:(?<error>[\s\w-]+)\b(?=\s+at\s+com\.)`?

Comment: thanks victor Not the output i'm expecting  from your regex
Regex = exceptions\.sessionException:(?<error>[\s\w-]+)\b(?=\s+at\s+com\.)?
your OUTPUT =  A1234- problem accessing the session at com

Expected OUTPUT = A1234- problem accessing the session

Comment: Here is the demo  - https://regex101.com/r/98mn8b/1. You are not using the regex I suggested.

Comment: So you're trying to get everything after `sessionException: ` but before `at`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(?i)[a-z][a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d]+)*\.sessionException: (.+?) at [a-z][a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d]+)*
```

- `(?i)`, toggle-on *"case-insensitive"* mode
- `[a-z][a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d]+)*`, matches any *Java package* name
- `\.sessionException:` , matches the text, *".sessionException: "*
- `(.+?) at` , captures all characters up to, *" at "*
- `[a-z][a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d]+)*`, matches any *Java package* name

Output

```
A1234- problem accessing the session
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time you post, please provide a few more positive examples. For what you submitted, this will capture into group 1:

```
(?:^com\..*?Exception:\s)(.*?)(?:\sat\scom.*)$
```